# ggplot2: Reversing the standard color gradient for a continuous variable

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors, continuous

I keep thinking that there must be an absolutely simple answer to my question, but I just can't seem to find it. Take this example plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(cty, displ, colour=displ, data=mpg)
```

This makes low values of *displ* appear in a dark blue and high values of *displ* appear in a light blue.

All I want to do is reverse the color gradient, because that seems more intuitive to me. I want low values of *displ* to have the light blue color and high values to have the dark blue color.

I know of this possibility to manually specify colors:

```
scale_colour_gradient(low="grey", high="black")
```

But I want to use the default colors, just in reverse.

Comment: `scale_colour_gradient(high="#132B43", low = "#56B1F7")` (Color codes taken from `?scale_colour_gradient`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the default color codes from `?scale_colour_gradient` and swap the arguments:

```
scale_colour_gradient(high = "#132B43", low = "#56B1F7")
```